# SDK in RubyMine not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jetbrains-ide, rubymine

For some reason, RubyMine is not finding my Ruby version I've installed in my Mac (OS Big Sur).

When I type `which ruby` in my terminal, I get this as a result:

```
git:(master) which ruby
/Users/sc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/bin/ruby
```

The weird issue is that it only happens in a specific project I'm working on.
I did a new rails app and RubyMine worked perfectly.. it did recognize the Ruby SDK.

In the project where I have the issue, this is what I see under **Preferneces**.
[image: Can't add a Ruby SDK]

Also this is what I see under **Run/Debug configuartions**.
Supposedly, the Ruby SDK is selected but it's not working at all.

[image: run/debug configuartions]

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean that the list of detected SDKs is empty but you can work with a new project? That list isn't per project so it's interesting how it's possible.

Comment: I found the solution:
I only needed to delete the .idea directory from the project via the terminal. I guess it had to do something with the cache. Thank you anyways! @Olivia